# Leave an empty field in birthday field and take only the date or the month? - Symfony2

Tags: datetime, symfony

I have a birthday field in my form, but I want the user to be able to choose whatever he wants - to fill `day, month and year`, or only `day and month`. Is there a way to leave the year empty?

Also I would like to ask if the input data is a DateTime object; can I somehow take only the day in some variable, or only the month...or it should be an array to do this? I want this because I want my app to inform the user if someone has a birthday today.

Here is my code:

```
    $builder->add('birthday', 'birthday', array(
        'widget' => 'choice',
        'format' => 'dd-MMMM-yyyy',
        'pattern' => 'dd-MMMM-yyyy',
        'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')-70),
        'label' => 'Birthday: ',
        'error_bubbling' => true,
        'required' => false));
```

Comment: So how did you manage to leave the year empty? I am trying to achieve the same but get validation errors if I don't fill in the year..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first part of your question, but the second part is easy:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-08-29');
$month = $date->format('m');
$day = $date->format('d');
echo $day;
echo $month;
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Your welcome. I edited my post because I wrote $date->format('m'); for both the month and the day, but i think you figured that out already :)